# How to position image in the center of MapView in react native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I am able to get it to the center without the mapview but I cant seem to get the image to the center with mapview. anyone able to do it on react native?

```
    render() {
         return (
            <View style = { styles.container }>

            <MapView style = { styles.mapView }></MapView>

             <View style = { styles.mapCenterMarkerView }>
                  <Image style={styles.mapCenterMarker}
                       source={{uri: this.state.markerIcon}}/>
                  </View>
    );
    }

var styles = StyleSheet.create({

            container: {
                flex: 1,
            },

            mapView: {
                flex: 1
            },

            mapCenterMarkerView: {
                top: 0,
                position: 'absolute', 
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            },

            mapCenterMarker: {
                width: 32,
                height: 32,
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I move the justifyContent: 'center' down from container for it to work. thank to you because i have a  inside the .

```
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    },

    mapView: {
        position: 'absolute', 
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
    },

    mapCenterMarkerView: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    },

    mapCenterMarker: {
        width: 32,
        height: 32,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
    },
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it work but I was unable to drag the map around because it was now covered up by a new component. To solve this I gave mapCenterMarkerView a width of 0 and used left and bottom to position my image

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the result you're looking for, but I had to remove the flex styling from the MapView.

https://rnplay.org/apps/TQGKjA

It looks like MapView doesn't allow child nodes. There's probably a way to do this without resorting to `position: 'absolute'` for the MapView but I'd have to play with it some more.

If you're new to flexbox like me, I've found this to be a good resource:
[flexboxin5.com](http://flexboxin5.com)

```
class SampleApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={ styles.container }>
        <MapView style={ styles.mapView }></MapView>
        <View style={styles.mapCenterMarker} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',

  },

  mapView: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 20,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
  },

  mapCenterMarkerView: {
    flex: 1,
  },

  mapCenterMarker: {
    width: 32,
    height: 32,
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  },
});
```